# locationManager:didChangeAuthorization vs locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization

Tags: ios, swiftui, core-location

In an iOS app using `SwiftUI` and `CoreLocation`. I need to keep an eye on the status of the permissions given by the user for location access.

Looking at the documentation for `CLLocationManagerDelegate`, it looks like I am supposed to use the *locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization* method.

The problem is this method never gets called (as far as I can see). Beside, the other method *locationManager:didChangeAuthorization* (supposed to be deprecated) seems to do the job.

If someone has any good advice, please let me know.

Comment: Which version of iOS are you running on?

Comment: I am using iOS 13.5.1.

Comment: The new method is only for iOS 14 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/3563956-locationmanagerdidchangeauthoriz. On iOS 13 you need to use the old method.

Comment: All right then.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization` is only available in iOS 14.  If you are running an earlier version of iOS you will need to use the older method, `locationManager:didChangeAuthorization`.  Although it is deprecated, it still works (and you must use it if you are supporting earlier iOS versions).

The reason for the delegate method change is covered in a [WWDC 2020 session](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10660) - In iOS 14 location permission has a time permission (never/when in use/always) and a new precision permission (high/low precision).

The original delegate method delivers the time permission to the delegate method, but doesn't deliver the precision information (since that permission didn't exist previously).

Rather than create a new delegate method that receives both the time and precision permission details, Apple have opted for a simple method that tells you something has changed. You then need to write code to check the `CLLocationManager` to determine the permissions you have and what to do about it.

Why they did it this way, we can only speculate, but I suspect that it gives them flexibility to add further permissions in the future without changing the method signature.

Comment: Why did they rename it, do we suppose? And why do they withhold the status info?